# Submit form, show div before refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, spinner

I wan't to show a spinner in maybe 2 seconds before reloading the page on my submit form.

```
<form class="ready" action="https://link.com" method="post">
<input name="test" type="submit" class="click" value="order"/>
</form>
```

I've got the spinner working:

```
<div class="thespinner"></div>    
<script>    
    $('.click').click (function () {    
    $(".thespinner").fadeIn("slow"); 
    });
</script>
```

Tried to simply add a link delay to the spinner with this code, but the data isn't going into the database:

```
<script>
$('.click').click (function (e) {
$(".thespinner").fadeIn("slow");
   e.preventDefault(); //will stop the link href to call the blog page

   setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = "https://link.com";
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

So - click button, show spinner 2 seconds then load action url/reload page (the data should be send while spinner is showing).

Thanks in advance!

P.s. I normally don't code javascript.

Comment: `window.location.href = "https://link.com";` doesn't send along the data. You need to submit the form instead: `$('.ready').submit();` What you also seem to be asking `(the data should be send while spinner is showing)` won't work that way at all though, that requires sending the form via ajax. It sounds like you want to recreate something you saw elsewhere without really understanding what the underlying mechanisms are. Why show a spinner for two seconds? If sending the data takes a while, and you want to show a spinner during that time, there's way better ways to achieve that.

Comment: We're making a request on a "calculation" and while the server calculates (sql-server) we wan't to make a small gif so people don't have to refresh the page again (and the database got time to send the data)

Comment: I posted an answer with my version; when you provide feedback, please include all errors you got, verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to send your form via ajax before redirecting

```js
$('#theForm').bind('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".thespinner").fadeIn("slow");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'someurl.htm',
        data: {},
        success: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "https://link.com";
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
          console.log(textStatus)
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.thespinner { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thespinner">Spinner</div>
<form id="theForm" >
  <input type="text" name="something" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Not working - but just realized we are putting data into a table in a database when submitting. Could that maybe be the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Not working" Is there a specific error? I assume you mean you're calling an API that is putting stuff into a database? That shouldn't have an effect as long as your API provides an appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to show a spinner during the AJAX request (i.e. the form data is sent in the background), then redirect after the request has finished:

```js
$('.ready').submit(function(e) {
  $(".thespinner").fadeIn("slow");
  e.preventDefault(); //will stop the link href to call the blog page
  $.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", $(this).serialize(), function(reply) {
    window.location.href = "https://link.com";
  });
});
```

```css
.thespinner {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="ready" action="https://link.com" method="post">
  <input name="test" type="submit" class="click" value="order" />
</form>
<div class="thespinner"><img src="https://loading.io/spinners/wave/index.wave-ball-preloader.svg"></div>
```